# Error redirecting after download in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

How do I redirect to another page for successfully exporting a laravel view file. I am using Laravel Excel 2.1.20. 
I researched and I discovered that this can't be done except I redirect first and then download the excel sheet. I did the below but still does not work.

**Here is my controller:**

```
$export = Excel::create('Request for Quote', function($excel) use($item, $request) {
    $excel->sheet('RFQ 1', function($sheet) use($item, $request) {
    $sheet->loadView('requests.send_rfq_pdf')
        ->with('item', $item)
        ->with('request', $request);
    });
});
session(['download.in.the.next.request' => $export]);
return back();
```

**My View:**

```
@if(Session::has('download.in.the.next.request'))
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url={{Session::get('download.in.the.next.request') }}">
@endif
```

Comment: have you tried to add ->download on Excel::create? Excel::create()->download('xlsx')